# TypeScript or ES6 version of lodash _.set() for deep object property assignment skipping null checks

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

the following code in JavaScript/TypeScript will fail if `b` is null:

`a.b.c = 1;`

Lodash provides a safe way to do this with https://lodash.com/docs/#set :

`_.set(a, 'b.c', 1);`

TypeScript introduced recently the optional chaining operator `?.` so we can safely address a nullable field like this:

`d = a.b?.c;`

but this doesn't work for assignments as above.
So, is there a quick way to do this in TypeScript or ES6? Maybe with `Object.assign()` or something?

Comment: `(a = a ?? {}).b = a?.b ?? {}).c = 1` (assuming those are the objects you want to create)

Comment: you can read about the javascript correspondent at https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining#not-supported, especially https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/issues/18, typescript might take different stances on this though :)

Comment: But... if `a.b` is `null`, then what to assign to `a.b`?

Comment: @Bergi interesting, but I think it makes the code less readable.

Comment: @FZs if `a.b` is null, you create `b` as an object, assign the field `c` to it, and assign `1` to `a.b.c`.

Comment: @ABOS thanks for the links, indeed, that's the issue.

Comment: @ABOS on second read, it looks like what they're considering is not what I'm asking here. In their interpretation, `a?.b?.c = 1` will skip the assignment if a or b are null. What I'm asking, is create a and b if they are null.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets, quote "We also discussed this question at TC39, and the committee did not seem so interested in adding this feature." So javascript won't support optional chaining assignment such as `a?.b?.c=1` at the moment. (typescript may, but not currently). You can still use lodash to do this though.

Comment: @ABOS I read the whole thread. Even if they *did* implement it, I am not sure they would implement what I asked. I know that I can use lodash for this, but I think that the idea of lodash is that all these methods should ideally be built into the language itself, so that eventually we won't need it.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets, AFAIK, they were discussing `a?.b?.c=1` for the use case you mentioned, as well as other use cases. e.g. do nothing if some property is null. It seems the committee did not think that is a key feature of the language, even though lodash implements it, it does not mean it will be "built into the language itself".

Comment: @ABOS ok, thanks for the links anyway, I guess I will have to live with lodash or Bergi's solution for now.

Comment: the problem with `lodash.set` is that we loose type safety